# Which WEKA Classifier for probability?

Tags: java, classification, weka, probability

I have the following problem: 
I have a dataset (arff), there are stored: character, key holdtime, user. 
So with this information, I have to calculate the probability for one person who is typing on keyboard.

If a person is typing on keyboard, same information as above will be extracted (user, key holdtime, user) and will be "compared" with the arff file. The result should be as follow: I have a dataset for user "John" in the arff-file. After that, one user types his username "John" and writes a text. The result should be the probability that the user "Johns" typing is equivalent with the dataset of "John" stored in the arff.
To 90% it is the right person, it is to 90% John.

I hope, I could explain my problem. My question is, which classifier should I take in this case? I did it with IBK, but if I have 15 persons, probability will be divided through 15 and I get small probabilities. 
Probability depends on the number of stored persons in arff. Or should I multiply the result with the number of persons to get the real probability?

Comment: When a user types "John", do you want the probability of him being John vs. not being John or find the user he is most similar to?

Comment: I mean, the question your classifier should answer is "He said he's John. Did he tell the truth?" or "He said he's John, but who is he really?"

Comment: That was exactly my question. All of these things are helpful, but in my case it would be inough to find: probability of him being John vs not being John. (when easy to implement find the user he is most similar to).
The Answer should look like this, exactly, He said he is John, but did he tell the truth?".

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  the sum of all the probabilities of a distribution has to be 1.

It is somehow true that you get "small probabilities" when you have more classes, but it's NOT because it is divided by the number of classes, so you won't find the probability you want multiplying the result with the number classes: it is not a probability anymore (it could easily become >1).

---

The probability distribution that you obtained using IBk is different from what you wanted: it tells you which one, between stored users, is more similar to the current user (probability of being John vs being Paul vs being Sarah etc.), indipendently from the name he said.

---

**The output you want** is the result of a binary classifier, but you'll need to train a classifier for every user you stored.

The training set of each classifier will be similar to the dataset you already have, but (in the case of John) there will be `isJohn` instead of `user`, and this new column will contanin `true` if `user` was John and `false` otherwise.

**EDIT**

```
    character, key holdtime,    user
           90,        150ms,    John
           70,        120ms,   Sarah
          100,        110ms,    Paul
```

will become

```
character, key holdtime,  isJohn
       90,        150ms,    true
       70,        120ms,   false
      100,        110ms,   false
```

The output distribution of this classifier is `is John` vs `is not John`.

To have the exact output you want, you must train a classifier for each stored user and call the right one depending on the name the current user said.

---

About which classifier to use, I think there is not a way to know which is the best for your case. I usually try some classifier and choose the best one

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Also I have to make a trainingset for each user, example: john.arff, sarah.arff... I do not understand how do you mean "is john" or "is not john"? Also I will have 4 columns, char, hold, is john, is not john? Or will it look like the *.arff at the moment? It does not make sense for me because I write always (example: 90, 150ms, John) it means John typed key 90 for 150ms. Should I make one .arff for each user and than calculate probability for this one user? For user John take john.arff and look what is probability for this user? Right?

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify what I mean for isJohn. Yes, you should make one .arff (and a different classifier) for each user, then for user John  you take john model and look what is his probability

Comment: Of course, you can include in the same arff the binary column for each user:
`character, key holdtime,  isJohn, isSarah,...\n
       90,        150ms,    true, false \n
       70,        120ms,   false, true \n
      100,        110ms,   false, false`
and then ignore the column you don't use (for John's classifier you ignore isSarah etc)

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you mean. It make sense thank you a lot for your answer and your help! I will try it at home, it really make sense. Thanks!